# Is it possible, and if so, how can I preserve lean meat using only salt at home?

Tags: food-safety, meat, food-preservation, salt

I have lean meat (4-5mm slices) which I would like to preserve using only salt. Is this possible to do at home? Do I need any kind of special curing salt or is regular fine?

I really don't care about taste, I just want the meat to be as safe and last as long as possible in room temperature.

Comment: Does drying count?

Comment: I believe it's possible with just salt/sugar or a brine, but I can't explain in detail so I won't post an answer. Have a look at these websites: https://www.thespruceeats.com/how-to-make-salt-pork-1327915 and https://www.goodtoknow.co.uk/recipes/salt-beef-recipe

Comment: hi!  when talking about meat, "lean" means having a lower than normal proportion of fat.  it sounds like you have thinly cut meat

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I don't have an oven so unless you mean air drying by just hanging it, I can't do it.

Comment: @jim Both thinly sliced and lean

Comment: It seems that you are looking how to make [jerky](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&ei=-odsXvvhMs-osgWKxJ2ABQ&q=jerky+recipe&oq=jerky+recipe&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.20896.22665..22996...0.0..0.140.769.1j6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i273.4Q0AA77fkFI&ved=0ahUKEwj7xozvuJnoAhVPlKwKHQpiB1AQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)

Comment: @MaxW Isn't that dried?